# Why is the oil pan plug not at the complete bottom of the system?

Tags: oil

I've noticed on my Jeep TJ, and my mom's Prius that the screw plugging the oil pan is not at the absolute bottom of the oil pan, but offset.

I know that the small amount of oil that gets trapped due to this is very small, and negligible when compared to other oil trapped in the system, but it's something that's always bothered me a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the reason is that you don't want the oil pan plug to be the first part in the system that hits a bump, tall rock or road debris.  Oil pans are pretty durable: if they hit a bump, they'll likely dent.  A bolt can be easily knocked askew, off thread or ripped completely out of its hole.

I've seen that last one happen right in front of me: tragic.

There's also the ancillary benefit that if you offset the drain plug towards the rear of the pan, it will drain better when you put the front of the car on jack stands.

Comment: I had half an answer which looked something similar to this and got side tracked. Good answer, Sir Bob!